# determine whether the series convergence $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{i^n}{n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series, divergent-series

determine whether the series convergence

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{i^n}{n} $

My teacher said it is convergent but
the ratio test is inconclusive and 
the root test is inconclusive

Comment: Does the sequence of partial sums converge? You may have to look at a few -- say, 4 -- subsequences. If they all converge, and to the same limit, then...

Comment: @ClementC. $4$? Isn't $2$ better?

Comment: Whatever works, I'd have gone for 4 (out of safety).

Answer (score 1):

The series is convergent but not absolutely convergent.  Absolute convergence would say that the series 
$$
\sum_1^\infty \left| \frac{i^n}{n} \right| = \sum_1^\infty  \frac{1}{n} 
$$
converges, and we know that is not the case.

However, we can break the series in question up as 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n}  = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{1}{2m} + i \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{1}{2m+1}
$$
and each of those alternating sign series can be shown to converge by grouping two terms together, getting a sum like
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{1}{2m} = \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{1}{k} -  \frac{1}{k+1} \right) = \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac1{k^2+k}
$$
which converges by the ratio test.

Comment: The last lines are unnecessary if you quote Leibniz Series Theorem. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Subdivide the Series in two sub-series: one over $2n$ and one over $2n+1$ and show that these converge.